# How to query a document collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm newbie at AngularFire and I'm trying to use Firestore Database with this structure:

```sh
/departments/<department_document_id>/workers/<worker_document_id>
```

Each *Department* document has some fields and a collection of workers, and each *Worker* document has it own fields, obviously.

I'm trying to get the workers list of a specific department, so in my DataService:

```js
getWorkers(departmentId: string) {
    this.departmentsCollection = this.afs.collection('departments', ref => ref.where('departmentId', '==', departmentId));
    // (?)
}
```

I supose that I should use *snapshotChanges()* with a *pipe()* in order to get the *DocumentChangeType* and query the *workers* collection, but I'm stucked at this point. I was trying it in different ways without results.

Any help / suggestions?

Edit: note that *departmentId* param is a field of a Department document, not the Firestore autogenerated ID.

Comment: Are your `department_document_id` and `departmentId` the same values?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen! No, <department_document_id> is the autogenerated document id by Firestore. The `departmentId` param is a field inside *Department* document.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are currently facing? What is the error you are getting?